# Counting value in increment

Tags: excel

So, I have this table:

```
 Emp_num     item
 87654       Headphone
 87654       Mouse pad
 20846       Mousepad
 45661       Headphone
 45661       iPhone
 45661       iPad
 45661       GoPro
```

And I want this:

```
 user_id     item            inc_count
 87654       Headphone       1
 87654       Mouse pad       2
 20846       Mousepad        1
 45661       Headphone       1
 45661       iPhone          2
 45661       iPad            3
 45661       GoPro           4
```

So, basically, I want to count orders of users incrementally so I could pick a maximum of 4 items per user only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this one?:

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW()),A2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the simper `COUNTIF` formula, and drag it down,

`=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)`

This counts the numbers between the `absolute reference` `$A$2` and the `relative reference` `A2`

Do not use `INDIRECT` in such cases, as adding or deleting a column will not give you the expected results. But the reference formula would change accordingly while adding or deleting rows/columns.

[image]